# Could I use Gift Card for Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I am a newbie Android developer and today when I would want to subscribe to console.developers.google.com' Google Cloud Platform , the site asked me for a ( Visa or Master ) credit or debit card number .
I have two question :
Could I use ( Master or Visa ) Gift Card Number for that ?
And if yes , what should be the minimum amount of that Gift Card ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gift cards are not acceptable for opening or maintaining an account. Gift cards are not linked to your identity. Google does not charge your credit/debit card, but does authorize a small amount to validate the card.

https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods